# Can't get row to delete PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

Here is my delete.php page:

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include("config.php");

//getting id of the data from url
$id = $_GET['id'];

//deleting the row from table
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id");

//redirecting to the display page (index.php in our case)
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

and the index.php page that is calling hit has:

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include("config.php");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC"); 
// using mysqli_query instead


while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="long"><?php echo $res['nameFirst'];?></td>
    <td class="long"><?php echo $res['nameLast'];?></td>
    <td class="long"><?php echo $res['email'];?></td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=$res[id]">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="delete.php?id=$res[id]" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

But when I click the Delete link, the page asks for confirmation, and then refreshes itself as it reloads index.php (itself) but the row in the table does not delete.

I am sure this is a simple fix but can't see the problem. I am presuming the error is somewhere in the $result line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$res[id]` must be keep inside php tag

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: As a note, it's usually a super bad idea to have a GET-style link that deletes things. Some browsers and web crawlers can trigger these links which can end up systematically deleting everything in your database. For this reason most people insist on putting them behind POST at the very least.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for the info on that. I value that experience and will make sure I don't expose my DB to injections. I remember Wordpress had a bad problem with injections at one stage. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because, you are messing up with the code of HTML and PHP.

And PHP code is not generating the id.

We can write PHP, HTML and Javascript code interchangeably in PHP file at any place.

But, you need to mention which is PHP code, which is HTML code (default one if nothing is specified) and which is Javascript code.

Modify the line:

```
<td><a href="delete.php?id=$res[id]" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a></td>
```

To:

```
<td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $res['id'];?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id="<?php echo $res['id']; ?>>Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="delete.php?id="<?php echo $res[id]; ?> onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a></td>
```

and in `delete.php`

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=".$id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't show the ID when you pass id parameter in the `inxde.php`. see the below correct code:

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include("config.php");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC"); 
// using mysqli_query instead


while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="long"><?php echo $res['nameFirst'];?></td>
    <td class="long"><?php echo $res['nameLast'];?></td>
    <td class="long"><?php echo $res['email'];?></td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=$res[id]">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed these lines:

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=$res['id']">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="delete.php?id=$res['id']" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a></td>
```

The `$res[id]` needs to be `$res['id']`, because you are passing the column name as string.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to echo

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $res[id] ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>
```